# Define argument type in function body of decorator

Tags: typescript, generics, reflection

The following decorator takes a function argument called `func`. The `func` will be executed within the returned function of the decorator - with an argument that's depending on the type of the property the decorator was called upon.

```
type ArgumentFunc = <T>(arg: T) => T;

function Decorator(func: ArgumentFunc): PropertyDecorator {
    return (prototype, field) => {
        const designType: string | number = Reflect.getMetadata('design:type', prototype, field);
        func<typeof designType>(designType);
    }
}

class Foo {
    @Decorator(string => string) // string is of type T, should be type string
    bar: string;

    @Decorator(number => number) // string is of type T, should be type number
    baz: number;
}
```

Can the argument of `func` be described when its type depends on the parent functions execution?

Comment: TS sees the decorator call as `Decorator(s => s)(Foo.prototype, "bar")`. This means that when the first call occurs (the one that contains the arrow function) ts will not yet know the field type. We can check that the arrow function is typed correctly and issue an error, but I don't think we can get inference to work for the arrow function.

Comment: See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2607